# What's the better way to communicate users in my WP7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

In my app i am maintaining the users .I need to provide the communication between the users.
For that i want to implement chat in my app.What's the better way to implement the chat in wp7?
I saw socket programming it seems to be security problem.
And i saw XMPP Framework it is licensed may need to package when deploy.
Tell me other alternatives to implement chat in WP7..
Please tell me ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One, another way to implement chat functionality will be to use WCF service. You can have a server, where you'll have WCF services running to grab and send the data. It has its own pros and cons. Like, it will be secure and you can implement/control WCF services easily. However, you'll always need to pull the data. Push will not work.